# SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException after switching to SOLR in Sitecore 8.1 Upd1

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I have switched my Sitecore 8.1 site from Lucene to SOLR as in this [link](https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/search/solr/Configuring-Solr-for-use-with-Sitecore-8/).

Everything went fine untill I rebuilt my indexes. All of them were rebuilt successfully except sitecore_master_index and sitecore_core_index. Both of them give similar errors, what do I need to do to fix it?

```
    Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">0</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/{8972abaa-542b-464e-963b-38d36ab550b8}?lang=da&amp;ver=1&amp;ndx=sitecore_master_index] unknown field '__display_name_t_da'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 group, Int32 groupSize)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.Commit()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.PerformRebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete, IndexingOptions indexingOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Rebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Comment: Use `Fiddler` application to check what is the request which returns `400` error.

Comment: The request seems to be a CheckStatus request only: &__PARAMETERS=CheckStatus&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__SOURCE=&__EVENTTYPE=&__CONTEXTMENU=&__MODIFIED=&__ISEVENT=1&__CSRFTOKEN=%2FwEFJGYyZDA4NzViLThkNmItNDdlMi1iZDViLTAxNDlkYzhjZDRiZg%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATE=93A1B03F9E584747B9ACAEB1FD082682&__VIEWSTATE=&dk_102781865=1&ErrorText=&ResultText=

Comment: I just noticed in the response the following: ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/{4ca2f825-0cf6-4a25-98ea-f16fd1ce469a}?lang=ja-jp&am.............. So is it trying to find items in different languages (ja, de, da...). I shouldn't have any languages other than english

Comment: Try first to add and then to remove Danish "da" language to Sitecore from Control Panel and reindex.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the master index but not the core one! Although i reset IIS and published my site

Comment: I just noticed that the languages inside the core DB do have ja, da, de although i didn't add them. But i can't delete them, the delete option is disabled. what should i do?

Comment: Remove those languages from `/sitecore/system/languages/` node in `core` db.

Comment: I can't remove them, the 'delete' option is disabled (in Core DB)

Comment: Which version of Solr do you use? Can you check if you have `<fieldType name="text_da"` in `schema.xml` for the `core` database Solr core?

Comment: ok, I get the 'this item is protected, click to unprotect' and then i can remove them. Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with `_da` suffix which is suffix for Danish text fields in Solr.

Try first to add and then to remove Danish "da" language to Sitecore from Control Panel and reindex.

For `core` database, remove unnecessary languages from `/sitecore/system/languages/` node in `core` db.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in Sitecore 8.0, the Solr Schema it generated added various language-specific field mappings (under `<fields>`) to the schema.xml output (which is mentioned in the blog link you reference).

In 8.1 Update 1 those field mappings are gone for some reason and you're left with Solr errors. I noticed this issue after reviewing the SOLR log that had reported:

```
.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=sitecore://core/{0b511b3d-c6eb-4284-aa75-c80fdca93db2}?lang=ja-jp&ver=1&ndx=**sitecore_core_index**] unknown field 'click**_t_ja**'
```

I added the following field mappings (again refer to your [blog link](https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/search/solr/Configuring-Solr-for-use-with-Sitecore-8/)) back into the Solr schema.xml file and Solr worked at that point.

```
<!-- added back in after 8.1 update 1 didn't generate them in schema -->
<dynamicField name="*_t_ar" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_bg" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_ca" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_cz" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_da" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_de" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_el" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_es" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_eu" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_fa" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_fi" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_fr" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_ga" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_gl" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_hi" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_hu" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_hy" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_it" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_ja" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_lv" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_nl" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_no" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_pt" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_ro" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_ru" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_sv" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_th" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_t_tr" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```